# Looking for realistic representation of angiosperm sperm cells during pollination

Tags: cell-biology, botany, reproduction

I've scoured Youtube, google, and a handful of my botany textbooks for a cellular-scale photo, animation, or video illustrating an angiosperm sperm cell during pollination/fertilization.

Unfortunately, other than an unclear glimpse of one in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CKVulkYnjgc) I've had essentially no luck.

Ideally, I'd like a microscope recording or a realistically-animated video demonstrating the accurate shape and movement of sperm along the pollen tube and into the ovary.

I think a video will better allow my botany students to visualize this process.

Please let me know if you can find or are aware of any such video or animation from any textbook supplemental materials, journal supplement, or via some reputable online resource.